# How to capture a function's `message` output?

Tags: message

Functions from some packages perform actions, but instead of returning the result directly, they display it in the message area using the `message` function. This appears to make composing such functions harder. The general question here is how to capture the `message`-emitted content without modifying the function itself (which would be messy).

An example is the `git-link` [package](https://github.com/sshaw/git-link/blob/fe2e8aa9/git-link.el#L511) and its `git-link` function. See `git-link--new`, called at the end of `git-link`:

```
(defun git-link--new (link)
  (kill-new link)
  ;; prevent URL escapes from being interpreted as format strings
  (message (replace-regexp-in-string "%" "%%" link t t))
  (setq deactivate-mark t)
  (when git-link-open-in-browser
    (browse-url link)))
```

I'm trying to make a wrapper for the `git-link` function to have `git-link` output into MacOS `pbcopy` - to have the git link automatically go into the MacOS copy buffer.

The `git-link` function however doesn't have a return value and it is difficult to work with its output without modifying the `git-link` package. Is it possible to capture what the function prints in the `message` area from a wrapper function, without modifying the original function itself?

**Edit:** based on the answer below and this [gist](https://gist.github.com/the-kenny/267162) this appears to do the job

```
(defun paste-to-osx (text)
    (let ((process-connection-type nil))
      (let ((proc (start-process "pbcopy" "*Messages*" "pbcopy")))
        (process-send-string proc text)
        (process-send-eof proc))))

(defun pbcopy-git-link ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'git-link)
  (paste-to-osx (current-kill 0))
)
```

The other answer (that uses function advising) appears to be a solution for the general case.

Comment: IMO, scraping the text of  a log message (the actual text as opposed to a status) to base your future processing on is a bad idea - sometimes that's a necessary evil, but it should be avoided if at all possible. In this case, the log message is a mangled version of what really matters, which is the `link` variable: the function gratuitously modifies that link (for no good reason actually) in order to use it in the log message, so if you copy that you have lost information. Getting the link out of the kill ring is probably the best (or maybe I should say the least worst) that you can do.

Comment: That's a good point. That's a critique of the `git-link` library (it must be a gentle one since it's free). Anyway, should the (`git-link`)[https://github.com/sshaw/git-link/blob/master/git-link.el#L730] function have just returned the `link` variable?

Comment: Instead of mangling the link, they could do `(message "%s" link)` in order to avoid the problem. But I didn't mean it as a criticism of `git-link`: it was more  a recommendation addressed to your request for capturing the message output. All I'm saying is: if you can get whatever you need in a way other than log scraping, you should probably go that way. It's not a panacea (e.g. using `current-kill` depends on the function doing `kill-new` so if that ever changes, it's going to break your function). And none of this is to be taken as an absolute prohibition: you do what you have to do...

Comment: Right, the current pattern is similar to a "format string vulnerability", whereby the mangling fixes the issues from the bug. Adding "%s" would remove the need for any mangling.

Answer (score 2):

Since it calls `kill-new` to insert the link into the `kill-ring`, you could just call `current-kill` to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to advise the `git-link--new` function with one that copies the current message to the kill ring. Like this:

```elisp
(defun test-message-foo nil
  (message "foo"))

(defun kill-test-message-foo nil
  (kill-new (current-message)))

(advice-add 'test-message-foo :after 'kill-test-message-foo)
```